# Swift type of shuffle()

Tags: swift

I want to test a function, passing in a shuffle function so I can Unit test the function adequately. In other words:

```
func testme(testArr: [Int], shufflefunction : Shufflefunction = .shuffle) -> [Int] {
    return tetsArr.shufflefunction
}
```

I know the syntax is incorrect; and that is the question.

What is the correct type of the shuffled function so I can make a reusable function for any particular shuffle implementation, as passed in the function above.

The second part of the problem is how to pass the standard shuffle() implementation as a default parameter for testing this function.

Comment: `func testme(testArr: [Int], shufflefunction : ([Int]) -> [Int]) -> [Int] { ...}`?

Comment: Do you want the shuffle to be a standalone function or do you want it in `extension Array { ... }`? Also do you want it generic or should it be a function that only works on arrays of ints?

Comment: Generic would be better, but I'm trying to pass shuffle as a function with a default parameter, so I use the default parameter while not Unit testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at `Array.shuffled`, you will see that it is actually a function that takes an array, and returns a `() -> [T]`:

[image]

Therefore, the type of `Array.shuffled` could be written as

```
(([T]) -> (() -> [T]))
```

We can then use this as our parameter type:

```
func testShuffle<T>(array: [T], function: (([T]) -> (() -> [T])) = Array.shuffled) {
    let shuffleFunction = function(array)
    let shuffledArray = shuffleFunction()
    // do stuff with shuffledArray...
}

// usage
extension Array {
    func myCustomShuffled() -> [Element] {
        // ...
    }
}

let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
testShuffle(array: arr, function: Array.myCustomShuffled)
```

Note that the same approach doesn't work with `Array.shuffle` (the mutating version), because Swift doesn't support partial applications on mutating functions.

You can also write the parameter type as `([T]) -> [T]`, then you would have to pass the default parameter like this:

```
func testShuffle<T>(array: [T], function: ([T]) -> [T] = { $0.shuffled() }) {
    let shuffledArray = function(array)
}
```